# C# async file transfer - waiting before continuing loop

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

I am trying to get my head around the changes in .NET 4.5, mainly the async features. To get my head around it I thought i would create a little app for archiving my massive photo collection. I learn best by doing so the application serves a double purpose.

I have read plenty MSDN articles on using async but I don't think I have a good enough understanding of it (because it's not working). My intention was to have each photo at a source folder copied to a destination folder based on its date taken (or created if taken meta data is missing). At the same time renaming it to a standard naming convention and showing the image as it is archived in an image box. I wanted the application to keep responding during the work, which is where async comes in. Now the app purpose is unimportant, the entire point was getting my head around async.

What actually happens is the app goes unresponsive, archives all the images as intended but the image box only shows the final picture. Async is kicking off the file transfer then moving on to the next image, kicking off the transfer then moving on etc etc so i end up with hundreds of open file streams rather than it waiting for each to close.

Any pointers in where I am going wrong would be appreciated. My understanding of using Tasks is shakey, returning a task serves what purpose?

imgMain is the imagebox in the XAML file. The async/await is in the archive method but showing all code as it may be relevant.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace PhotoArchive
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private string Source 
    {
        get { return txtSource.Text; }
        set { txtSource.Text = value; }
    }

    private string Destination
    {
        get { return txtDestination.Text; }
        set { txtDestination.Text = value; }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnBrowseDataSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogue = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialogue.ShowDialog();
        Source = dialogue.SelectedPath;

    }

    private void btnBrowseDestination_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialogue = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialogue.ShowDialog();
        Destination= dialogue.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Source, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var result = from i in files
                     where i.ToLower().Contains(".jpg") || i.ToLower().Contains(".jpeg") || i.ToLower().Contains(".png")
                     select i;


        foreach (string f in result)
        {
            DateTime dest = GetDateTakenFromImage(f);
            Archive(f, Destination, dest);
        }

    }

    private async void Archive(string file, string destination, DateTime taken)
    {

        //Find Destination Path
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(destination);
        sb.Append("\\");
        sb.Append(taken.ToString("yyyy"));
        sb.Append("\\");
        sb.Append(taken.ToString("MM"));
        sb.Append("\\");

        if (! Directory.Exists(sb.ToString()))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(sb.ToString());
        }

        sb.Append(taken.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_H_mm_ss_"));
        sb.Append((Directory.GetFiles(destination, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()));
        string[] extension = file.Split('.');
        sb.Append("." + extension[extension.Length-1]);


        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
        using (FileStream ds = File.Create(sb.ToString())) 
        {
            await fs.CopyToAsync(ds);
            fs.Close();
            File.Delete(file);
        }

        ImgMain.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sb.ToString()));
    }

    //get date info
    private static Regex r = new Regex(":");

    public static DateTime GetDateTakenFromImage(string path)
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
            {
                PropertyItem prop;

                try
                {

                    prop = img.GetPropertyItem(36867);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    prop = img.GetPropertyItem(306);
                }

                string dateTaken = r.Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(prop.Value), "-", 2);
                return DateTime.Parse(dateTaken);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not an expert on the new async/await features of .Net 4.5 but one thing that does stand out to me is that the only thing you are running asynchronously is the file copy. I'm sure you will get some useful answers though with better guidance.

Comment: @DanielKelley What else would you want to run asynchronously?

Comment: @svick As per your answer - everything inside of Archive. Apart from `await`ing `fs.CopyToAsync` everything else was tying up the UI thread.

Comment: @DanielKelley It still is, even if you `await` the result of `Archive()`. But: 1. It shouldn't be a problem, there are no long operations I can see in there. 2. Those operations don't have async versions.

Comment: @svick Maybe my comment was badly phrased - I did not mean every action should be performed using an async method (e.g. file deletions). I meant he was awaiting the file copy rather than his call to `Archive` - which he couldn't do due to the signature of the method being incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My understanding of using Tasks is shakey, returning a task serves what purpose?

The `Task` is a representation of the async operation. When the `Task` completes, it means the operation completed. And you can `await` the `Task`, which means you will asynchronously wait for it to complete (not blocking the UI thread).

But if you make your method `async void`, there is no way to wait for the operation to complete. When the method returns, you know that the async operation was started, but that's it.

What you need to do is to change `Archive()` to return a `Task`, so that you can wait for it to complete in your event handler. The `Task` will be returned automatically, you don't need to (or can) add any `return`s.

So, change the signature of `Archive()` to:

```
private async Task Archive(string file, string destination, DateTime taken)
```

And then `await` it in your event handler (which you also need to change to `async`):

```
private async void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // snip

    foreach (string f in result)
    {
        DateTime dest = GetDateTakenFromImage(f);
        await Archive(f, Destination, dest);
    }
}
```

In general, `async void` methods should be used *only* for event handlers. All other `async` methods should be `async Task` (or `async Task<SomeType>` if they return some value), so that you can `await` them.

Comment: Did you forget to update the signature of `Archive`? (+1 from me as a nice clear explanation)

Comment: Great explanation, just testing it now. I think weekend reading might be needed to better understand what Tasks can do.

Comment: Worked great. Now does what I expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the `Archive` method, since you only want a single instance of the `Archive` method to be running at any single point in time. Note that in your implementation you are starting a lot of `Archive` instances and not really releasing the UI-thread.

Modifications to your code:

- Add `async` to `btnSort_Click`
- Add return type `Task` to `Archive`
- Await `Archive` in `btnSort_Click`

TIP:
If the first method called (in your case `btnSort_Click`) is not async, it will not be seen as async "from the outside", ie your window and UI-thread.

Comment: You can't `await` an `async void` method.

Comment: I had tried that but the await throws the error 'void is not awaitable'. This is where my lack of understanding of tasks comes in i suppose. The Archive method needs to return a task? To what purpose though? Cheers

Comment: @James Sorry for that mistake, the return type needs to be `Task` for it to be "awaitable".